# Should I use 'using namespace std'

Tags: c++, namespaces

Should I use `using namespace std;` ?
I saw some posts saying that using namespaces is a bad practice. So I just want to clarify this.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or should I keep going like this

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also please elaborate the reason.

Comment: I use it for small programs only.

Comment: dup: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4641116)

Comment: I know it's a duplicate but it's a really searchable question title. With the amount of `using namespace std;` we see around, I think this is still needed. Upvoted!